# Why do some folders have their date modified overwritten when copying them to an external drive, but others don't?

Tags: macos, finder

I just copied over some folders from my documents folder to a thumbdrive. Most of them copied over as expected, but for some reason, some folders have had their date modifed overwritten to when they were copied across, but not others. Is there a reason why only some have been affected? I have checked the files inside them, and their dates remain unchanged.

Comment: *How* did you copy the files? What's the file systems of the source and destination of those folders?

Comment: Can you provide examples?  The question, as written is a bit ambiguous and without putting eyes on them, we can oly make guesses.

Comment: @Thinkr I copied them using cmd+c and moved them from my documents folder to the usb drive I was using.

Comment: @Allan Not sure what you mean. The date modified for a selection of folders has just changed, and is now different than the date modified was originally, but the other files in the folders remain unchanged, and the date modified of other folders copied from the same directory at the same time is also unchanged.

Comment: We can’t see over your shoulder - can you take a screen shot of what you’re seeing?  Or, better yet, can you go into terminal and capture the output of the directory with the `ls -lae` command?

Comment: Thanks, you have answered the first question. Now the second: *What's the file systems of the source and destination of those folders?*